# Add members to JavaPoet

Tags: java, junit, javapoet

I tried to create TestSuite in JavaPoet api.
I have List with my junit classes in testClasses, so i want to add member annotation but addmember allow us to add only one object at time, so how i can add All list?

```
.addAnnotation(AnnotationSpec.builder(SuiteClasses.class)
.addMember("value", "$T.class", testClasses.toArray()).build())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting a variable for the builder.

```
AnnotationSpec.Builder ab = AnnotationSpec.builder(SuiteClasses.class);
for (String s : strings) {
  ab.addMember(s, "$S", lookup(s));
}
AnnotationSpec annotation = ab.build();
```

Comment: look for my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.squareup.javapoet.AnnotationSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile;
import com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Javapoet {

    public void generateTestSuite(List<Class> testClasses) throws IOException {
        MethodSpec test = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("test").addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC).returns(void.class)
                .addAnnotation(Test.class).build();

        TypeSpec testSuite = TypeSpec.classBuilder("TestSuite").addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC).addAnnotation(

                AnnotationSpec.Builder ab = AnnotationSpec.builder(SuiteClasses.class);
        for (String s : strings) {
            ab.addMember(s, "$S", lookup(s));
        }
        AnnotationSpec annotation = ab.build();


        JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("", testSuite).build();

        Path path = Paths.get("src/test/java");
        javaFile.writeTo(path);
    }
}
```